# How to switch to postman mode to debug requests

Tags: postman

Looks like I accidentally switched postman to some mode : https://prnt.sc/1091zyc

and I can not return to common mode to continue working on requests in my collection.

Howe to return to common mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an older version of the app and you currently have that in 'browse' mode, on the **bottom right menu bar**, you can see a toggle to put it back in 'build' mode.

[image: Postman]

V8 doesn't have that switch and everything is in the same view.

Comment: Sorry do not see where  toggle to 'build' mode :  https://prnt.sc/1093gyn.  Where can I check postman version ?

Comment: That's the top right menu, look down at the bottom 

Comment: Thanks, found! I failed to find postman version in synaptic or in console with command dpkg -s postman | grep Version.  I have kubuntu 18. Looks I have old version of postman ?

Comment: Can you accept the answer by clicking on the tick please. You will find the version be hitting the cog icon and then  `Settings > About`. Then look like v7.